# Where can I find some basic information about RenderScript?

Tags: android, renderscript

I am looking for some information about renderscript ?

I already know the part of display have deprecated , so I want to focus on compute part.

Is there any useful information can give me ?

Answer (score 1):

From the google documentation [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html)

Comment: hey man , google documentation is good , but not the things i want ;-D

Comment: yep , because google documentation is a little bit difficult , i am llok for some basic thing to learn renderscript

Answer (score 1):

[RenderScript](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=renderscript%20android&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/package-summary.html&ei=3G-kUNTIAsrDswaV2IDwCg&usg=AFQjCNFA1kFx9SqPOIXpcLj7RfbmVqKJQw)

[Getting started with RenderScript](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=renderscript%20android&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAC&url=http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/getting-started-with-renderscript-on-android/&ei=3G-kUNTIAsrDswaV2IDwCg&usg=AFQjCNEgJMwdmKbEivzPwhs3p42e1zWb7g)

Many other links will be available if you just google :)

Comment: Ok.. Sorry. I thought that would be useful

Comment: ;-D , don't be said , you link is useful , but the display part of renderscript have already deprecated , so i am looking for compute part information

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/103/ has a nice easy to follow demonstration of adding a compute kernel to an app for image processing.